# AWS Step Functions: Workflow to handle deleting temporary tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am working on setting up an AWS Step Functions workflow. The workflow involves several stages, including creating temporary tables, running tasks in `Stages-2` and `Stage-3`, and then cleaning up the temporary tables. My current workflow looks like:
[image]
I want to handle error in `Stage-2` and `Stage-3` and irrespective of the their outcome, I still want to run the `TempTableDrop` stage.

One thing that comes to my mind is to have something like:

[image]

But I do not want to Duplicate the `TempTableDrop` state. Is there any other way of handling this? If I catch the error and from `Stage-2` and `Stage-3`  and send it to `TempTableDrop` instead of `TempTableDrop(1)`, is there any way of sending the result to either `JobSucceeded` or `Fail State` based on the outcome of `Stage-2` and `Stage-3` ?

Any help or sample Step Functions definition would be highly valuable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point the two error fallbacks to a new [Pass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) state.  It outputs a payload that we can identify as an error downstream:

```json
"AddErrorMarker": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Result": {
    "hasError": true,
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.error",
  "Next": "TempTableDrop"
}
```

The happy and unhappy paths now converge on `TempTableDrop`.  Then add a new [Choice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) state that branches to `Success` or `Fail` depending on an `"IsPresent": "$.error"` condition.